# LyX texcount custom converter

Tags: lyx, conversion, texcount

Is it possible to define a new Converter in LyX so I can use `texcount -sub` and produce a `.txt` file with the statistics of the file?

I was thinking in going to

> Tools -> Preferences -> Converters

and redefine the `Lyx -> Plain Text` option, but it does not seem to work

Comment: What do you mean by "does not seem to work" ? What are the exact steps you took to add a converter? What is the line in your preferences file (on Ubuntu this is ~/.lyx/preferences. On other OS's go to Help > About to find your user dir) after you create your converter? Have you read Help > Customization > 3.3 Converters ? Which version of LyX are you using?

Comment: Just in case you didn't know about it, does Tools > Statistics satisfy your needs?

Comment: Hi. I tried to use the `LyX -> Plain Text` converter and put the `texcount -sub` command. The statistics tool is too basic and I think it is counting the figures and footnotes. The `-sub` option in texcount gives a more detailed summary for the words number in each section. I will take a look to the customization

Comment: OK, post back if you still have questions after reading it (and please answer the questions I asked you). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I created a new entry in  `Tools -> Preferences -> File Formats` called TexCounter with the `txt`  Extension. Then in `Converters` I added `Latex(plain) -> TeXCounter` with the command: `texcount -sub $$i` . The new converter appears in the LyX menu (File -> Export) but I do not get a txt file with the `texcount` output. Am I doing something wrong? I tried to do something similar to this topic http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114285/pythontex-workflow-with-lyx but I can't get what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `texcount` writes to STDOUT, where I think you're assuming it's writing to a file somewhere.

The following works for me on Ubuntu:

1. Create a file, `mytexcount.sh`.
2. Make it executable.
3. Put the following as the contents of the file:

   `texcount -sub "$1" > /path/to/output/mycount.txt`
4. Change your converter command to

   `/path/to/mytexcount.sh $$i`

You can customize things further with other converter variables. See Help > Customization for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works. I realised that, to avoid creating a .sh file, it could be used `texcount -sub $$i > $$o` in the converter :)

Comment: I had that the first time, but I had mistyped the variables. Now I can produce a Texcount without specifying paths, and it seems more general. Thanks again for your help

Comment: Glad it works for you. That way wasn't working for me for some reason.

Comment: TeXcount also has an option `-out=_filepath_` which can be used instead of `> _filepath_` and may be more robust.

Comment: @EinarRødland +1. Note that texcount version 2.3 does not have this option. Version 3.0 does (and possibly earlier).

Comment: @scottkosty: Right! The `-out=` option came with version 3.0.