# Running pythonTeX with Lyx under Windows

Tags: lyx, windows, python, pythontex

I am trying to get [pythonTeX](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex) running with Lyx 2.4.1 in Windows 10 by following [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114285/pythontex-workflow-with-lyx/114708#114708) post. I have installed pythonTeX and verified it is working when running a test file with the commands:

1. `pdflatex test.tex` (this generates pytx code)
2. `pythontex.bat test.tex` (parses pytx code)
3. `pdflatex test.tex` (this generates pdf)

In Lyx, I set up the file formats as discussed in the previous post:

1. format=`LaTeX (pytex1)`; shortname=`pytex1`; extensions=`pytex1ext`
2. format=`LaTeX (pytex2)`; shortname=`pytex2`; extensions=`tex`
3. format=`PDF (pytex)`; shortname=`pytex`; extensions=`pdf`

And converters:

1. from=`LaTeX (pdflatex)`; to=`LaTeX (pytex1)`; converter=`pdflatex $$i`; extra=`latex=pdflatex`
2. from=`LaTeX (pytex1)`; to=`LaTeX (pytex2)`; converter=`pythontex.bat $$i`; extra=``
3. from=`LaTeX (pytex2)`; to=`PDF (pytex)`; converter=`pdflatex $$i`; extra=`latex=pdflatex`

which follows the test run described above.

This isn't working as expected; step 1 of the conversion works fine, i.e. `pdflatex` is run on the tex file to create the pytx code. However, step 2 fails with the following message:

```
09:11:07.158: pythontex.bat "test.pytex1ext"
09:11:07.188: 
09:11:07.193: C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\lyx_tmpdir>python "c:/users/xxx/documents/localtexmf/scripts/pythontex/pythontex.py" test.pytex1ext 
09:11:07.575: Traceback (most recent call last):
09:11:07.580:   File "c:/users/xxx/documents/localtexmf/scripts/pythontex/pythontex.py", line 50, in <module>
09:11:07.584:     import pythontex2 as pythontex
09:11:07.587:   File "c:\users\xxx\documents\localtexmf\scripts\pythontex\pythontex2.py", line 60, in <module>
09:11:07.590:     import multiprocessing
09:11:07.592: ImportError: No module named multiprocessing
..\..\..\src\support\Systemcall.cpp (292): Systemcall: 'pythontex.bat "test.pytex1ext"' finished with exit code 1
Error: Cannot convert file
```

This fails obviously because in `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\lyx_tmpdir` there is no file `test.pytex1ext` which is the extension defined in format 1 but just the file `test.tex`. So what happens when i change the extension to `tex` instead? Then the second step tries to run:

```
pythontex.bat 'tmpfile.out'
```

which obviously also does not exist. Who has an idea how to sort this out? I am close but can't get it to work.

Note: The ImportError on the `multiprocessing` module worries me slightly as well as it is working fine when running `pythotex.bat` from the command prompt, but i want to get the extension right first and see if the issue remains.

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out the `ImportError` was part of the [problem](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex/issues/72); apparently LyX uses its own version of Python. To remedy this i replaced the version of Python with a softlink to my installed version of Python. Alternatively, you could set the correct PATH variable in the preferences.

The second thing which caused problems was the creation of the pdf in step 1; Lyx won't compile a new pdf if a pdf is already present. A quick workaround for me was to insert the following lines into `pythontex.bat` before the call to `pythontex.py`:

```
set argin=%1
del %argin:pytex1ext=pdf%
```

Note that this will skip any other generated pdf in case such files are used as image formats with vector graphics.