# Using PythonTex in Lyx2.2.2 under Windows 10

Tags: lyx, pythontex

I have this simple ERT code in LyX:

```
Say hello Python

\begin{pycode}
print ('Hello, \\LaTeX')
\end{pycode}
```

The output (I click on the pair of eyes) is simply:

Say hello Python

It seems that the Python code is not being executed.

Has anyone encountered this before, and if so, is there a neat solution?

Comment: Welcome, you should write a MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/what-makes-a-good-mwe or https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that?.

Comment: By clicking on the pair of eyes you're running pdflatex, not pythontex. You have to set up the default output format. Check what's in Tools>Preferences  and  Document>Settings.

Comment: I thought that the package pythontex would run the Python code in the background and once that is completed, then the pdflatex would output to a pdf file. I am not getting any errors, it's just that the Python code is not being seen.

Comment: No, that is incorrect. As described in the manual, you need to run `pythontex filename` in between runs of `pdflatex filename`. See if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114285/pythontex-workflow-with-lyx helps you setting up LyX to run `pythontex` as well.