# Lyx and python tex

Tags: lyx

I try to execute a python script in LyX documents, using python text. When I compile the document it returns no error as I see, and I just have some "??" where I expect python answers. I have the same thing with Textmaker.

I follow the solution from here, [Pythontexworkflow with Lyx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114708/200930), I did this solution 3 times and each time it give me a long-running compilation with at the end a "pdflatex $ i" error. And after I apply the format and converter i am unable to compile in a pdf file. When I compile a document it opens an Html browser page.
I don't know what i do wrong, i would like to understand how to run python command in lyx documents.

thanks for your help

Comment: Oo, information i run under windows, i try to check the python path.

Comment: Hello guys, no ideas ?

Comment: Did someone make this solution works ?

Comment: Hello guys, noone had answers or explanation ?