# Package to parse C/C++ code in LaTex document and output in the original document

Tags: packages

I am a beginner in writing code in LaTeX (and I use LyX). Being a student of statistics, I use R and have already used the `Rnw(knitr)` module to output the result of an R code chunk in the output pdf (using the traditional Sweave syntax). As stated by Yihui Xie [here](https://yihui.org/knitr/demo/minimal/),

> 'knitr extracts R code in the input document, evaluates it and writes the results to the output document'.

Out of curiosity, I surfed the internet a bit and found [pythontex](https://ctan.org/pkg/pythontex?lang=en) and as stated by Geoffrey Poore in [here](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex),

> 'PythonTeX executes code in LaTeX documents and allows the output to be included in the original document. It supports Python as well as Bash, JavaScript, Julia, Octave, Perl, R, Raku (Perl 6), Ruby, Rust, and SageMath'.

Here's the [Conference Presentation](https://youtu.be/yIO4l0zHGjw) of pythontex given by Geoffrey M. Poore himself. Now setting up LyX to work with pythontex can be done as described in [this TeX SE question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/114285/229605).

I was wondering if the same can be done with C/C++ codes also. I surfed the internet but couldn't get any satisfactory results.

Does such a package exist? If not, is there a specific reason as to why this is not made till now?

Comment: I once wrote something that does that, but I never put it on CTAN. The process is the same as for sagetex, which is pretty simple.