# How do I compile latex file on remote python kernel?

Tags: compiling

Is there any technique to compile latex files on a remote python kernel in realtime?
For example, I have a very big lyx file (a version of latex compiler). If I compile it on a normal computer it take up to 20 minutes each time.
However, if I compile it on a university supercomputer it merely takes 2 minutes, using python. Can I do this in real time without transferring the file to the supercomputer every time?

Comment: if this question should be in stack overflow. please move it there.

Comment: I'm skeptical that Python is involved.  Are you sure about that?  I would assume it's just that the supercomputer is 10x faster.  Depending on the supercomputer, it might be possible to set up git to get the latest version of the file without much trouble.

Comment: may be python is not involved. I just use PythonTeX to compile tex files. with some dirty ways to embed it in lyx  https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex 
  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114285/pythontex-workflow-with-lyx

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No, supercomputer supports only CUI. There are lyx files compilers in python. See this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114285/pythontex-workflow-with-lyx                              For example, ipython console supports remote kernel.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle lyx has command line also. so I can install lyx on supercomputer using sudo apt. then I can create a bash file that executes a lyx command to convert .lyx files to.tex files. then I can use any python library. I am wondering if can write a script to send the lyx file via FTP and execute the command on supercomputer using some automated way. or may be I can connect the lyx compiler to a remote python kernel. I know, may its not possible. May be this link can help me out. https://wiki.lyx.org/Tips/Compiling

Comment: That is not a lyx compiler in Python.  That is talking about how to have the regular lyx compiler also run a Python script.  But I'm confused about your question in general.  I understand that you want to compile on the supercomputer, and that it's annoying to have to transfer the file to the supercomputer every time (I'm dealing with that currently as well).  But you need some way to have the file updated on the supercomputer.  Or are you looking for some way to streamline that workflow?